# Golang GORM: Define a Follower/Following many2many association

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to implement a many2many relationship between a `Profile`s `Followers` and `Following`. My requirements are:

1. The join table should have `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt` and `DeletedAt` fields. I therefore need a custom jointable
2. It should be easy to retrieve the `Following` from the `Profile`s `Id`. I think I need an index on the `Following` Id
3. Less important, it should also be computationally cheap to retrieve the `Profile`s `Followers`, i.e. the reverse relationship.

Among what I've tried I consider this the most reasonable attempt:
[`NoIdBaseModel` contains the required time fields.]

```golang
type Profile struct {
    NoIdBaseModel
    Id           string    `gorm:"primaryKey;not null;size:128;"`
    Followers    []*Profile `gorm:"many2many:follower_relationships;foreignKey:FollowerId;association_foreignkey:FollowingId"`
    Following    []*Profile `gorm:"many2many:follower_relationships;foreignKey:FollowingId;association_jointable_foreignkey:FollowerId"`
    Comments  []Comment  `gorm:"foreignKey:ProfileId"`
}
```

and

```golang
type FollowerRelationship struct {
    NoIdBaseModel
    FollowingId string  `gorm:"index:idx_profile_follower,unique;primaryKey"`
    Following   Profile `gorm:"foreignKey:FollowingId;references:Id"`
    FollowerId  string  `gorm:"index:idx_profile_follower,unique;primaryKey"`
    Follower    Profile `gorm:"foreignKey:FollowerId;references:Id"`
}
```

and in the GORM constructor:

```golang
    if err := db.SetupJoinTable(&entities.Profile{}, "Followers", &entities.FollowerRelationship{}); err != nil {
        logger.Error("migration error", zap.Error(err))
        return &ProfileRepository{}, err
    }
```

I get however:

```
 migration error {"error": "invalid foreign key: FollowerId"}
```

But I thought this is in fact a foreign key on the jointable. Trying to implement this many2many relationship in SQL left me confused.

I'm stuck as the docs do not provide much context and chatgpt also returns uncompilable code. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to reference the fields to each other?